# Egress window in detached garage

Tags: egress

I'm converting my detached garage to a bedroom and the garage door has been covered in drywall so the only exit is a sliding glass door. The windows don't qualify to be egress windows, but I do I need a second exit since the sliding glass door leads outside? Thanks!

Comment: Add a door if the windows don't work.  If a second hand door will probably be much cheaper than a new window.

Comment: I believe if you have a sliding glass door , that is your egress point and the window does not need to qualify if the bedroom is the one full area.

Comment: If you have a bedroom with one door the goes to other sections of the house/basement/garage, then you need a second way to get outside from inside the bedroom.  If the sliding door is in the bedroom that is perfect.

Comment: @crip659 it's a detached garage, so no door going to other sections of the house.  I assume.